# Why are product_id and item_id part of the request to update stock through the API?

Tags: api, magento2.2.2

I'm developing an application to integrate with the Magento inventory API, and I'm confused about the fields `product_id` and `item_id`.

I'm PUT-ing to the API `/V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}`

The body of the request looks like

```
{
  "stockItem": {
    "item_id": 1,
    "product_id": 1,
    "stock_id": 1,
    "qty": 15
  }
}
```

However, I can leave off the `product_id` and/or the `item_id`, and the request still seems to work correctly, and updates the inventory.

```
{
  "stockItem": {
    "item_id": 1,
    "stock_id": 1,
    "qty": 20
  }
}

{
  "stockItem": {
    "stock_id": 1,
    "qty": 25
  }
}
```

Both of the above requests also update the product's inventory.  So my questions are

- What is the difference between `product_id` and `item_id`.  I know that `product_id` is used as the primary key in the products table, so then what does `item_id` do?
- Why are `product_id` and `item_id` both parameters in this request ([and shown in Magento's documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html)) if neither one of them appears to be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body parameters come from the used interface `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface`.
That does not mean that all this parameters have any impact on every request. The method triggered by the API, `updateStockItemBySku`
in `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry`, uses them as follows:

- If you update the stock for a given product sku (i.e. that product has already a corresponding stock item), the `item_id` is ignored.
- The parameter `product_id` of stock item is always ignored, the used `product_id` is always the one found in the product entity associated to the given `{productSku}` path paramer.

Regarding the difference between `item_id` and `product_id`: The first one is the id of the stock item, the primary key of the table `cataloginventory_stock_item`, 
the `product_id` is the `entity_id` in the table `catalog_product_entity` of the product associated to this stock item.

But as you have correctly observed none of them really have an impact if you update stock.

I hope that makes the procedure a little clearer :-)

There is only one thing I don't understand in the process: What is the sense of the requiered `{itemId}` path parameter? This is not even passed to the method as far as I can see.